# Menu button position when not active but at media screen size 600px

Tags: css, html, position

Menu button position when not active but at media screen size 600px.
I have screenshots showing what I need it to do, I'm not worried about the look of the menu, but I've been having trouble with the menu button not where I want it after media screen resize.

[**Codepen demo**](https://codepen.io/techatyou/pen/JZyqQa)

I want the menu button in the position it is after clicking it, but it doesn't work how I want it to.

screenshots:

[image]



[image]

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Firstly, don't scream your question title, and that StackOverflow demands proper grammar. StackOverflow is not an informal discussion board. Also is it not clear what you exactly are expecting, and what you are asking. It is not recommended to post a picture as a link to the picture.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Will do so in my next post.

Comment: @SirExotic As i'm sure your aware, this was my first post here.  A simple please read the rules and policies would have sufficed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this code**

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-align: center; padding:0; margin:0;
}
.imglogo {
 float: inherit;
 width: 250px;
 height: 67px;
 background: url(img/logo.png) no-repeat center;
 display: block;
}

.topnav {
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #333;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px grey;
 
}

.topnav a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #86cc53;
  color: white;
}
.transbox {
  background-color: #86cc53;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 right: 10px;
  }
  .topnav.responsive {position: absolute; left:0; right: 0; top:0;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<i class="imglogo"></i>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onClick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">Services</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about" class="transbox">About</a>
</div>

<div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
  <h2>This Site is Under Construction.</h2>
  <p>In need of any computer, networking repair/setup/configuraion or consulting contact my cell leave a message for NICK. CELL:xxx-xxx-xxx</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you all will try your suggestions when I get off work